# ajax "post" request failed

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using ajax for the first time and passing data to another file using ajax request. The request goes through if I pass it using get which is by default but the moment I change it to post it does not work.

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'pageAjax2.php',
            data:'name='+name,
            success: function(data){
                $('#content').html(data);
            }
      })
```

If I remove the type:'POST'; everything works but if have it in the code nothing works . Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: try `data: { name : name },`

Comment: What does `nothing works` mean? The AJAX request fails, the response fails? Is `pageAjax2.php` using `$_GET` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

All good here. What version of jQuery are you using ?

I'll post my code :

File jq.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(function(){
        var name = 'Telmo Dias';

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'pageAjax2.php',
            data:'name='+name,
            success: function(data){
                $('#content').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

File pageAjax2.php :

```
<?php echo "Hello ".$_POST['name'];?>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys i just checked and pageAjax2.php had been set to get instead of using post so i just changed it to post and everything works now
thank you